# Find All Fonts with "Arial" in their Name

Tags: vbscript, fonts, wsh

The code below finds the font "Arial", but I would like to find all fonts that are Arial in the title (so "Arial Rounded", "Arial Unicode", etc.). I should be able to use a wild card right? I must not know where it goes. Could someone help me echo all fonts that have "Arial" in them?

```
Const FONTS = &H14&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(FONTS)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
For Each objItem In colItems
    If objItem = "Arial" Then
        Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it already. You just need to check if the name of the item contains the (sub)string "Arial":

```
For Each objItem in colItems
    If InStr(LCase(objItem.Name), "arial") > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo objItem.Name
    End If
Next
```

The lowercasing of the name is to make the comparison case-insensitive.

An alternative to the (somewhat clumsy) `InStr` comparison would be to test the item name with a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "arial"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each objItem in colItems
    If re.Test(objItem.Name) Then
        WScript.Echo objItem.Name
    End If
Next
```